# Java: Error with calling the WriteUTF method

Tags: java, text-files, multidimensional-array, filewriter

I'm having problems with writing a 2d, user-inputted array to a text file. My code thus far (in the Saving method, at least) is:

```
`public static void Save(String[][] EntryList)
{
   try {
        String[][] content = EntryList;
        File file = new File("CBB.dat");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        InputStream instream;
        OutputStream outstream;

        instream = new DataInputStream( new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))); // buffers the data stream
        outstream = new DataOutputStream( new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for (int row = 0; row < EntryList.length; ++row)
        {
                outstream.writeUTF(EntryList[row][1]); 
                outstream.writeUTF(EntryList[row][2]);
                outstream.writeUTF(EntryList[row][3]);
                outstream.writeUTF(EntryList[row][4]);
                outstream.writeUTF(EntryList[row][5]);
            }
              outstream.close();

            }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        }`
```

However, when I try to compile, I get the error that Java "cannot find symbol - method WriteUTF(String)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no `writeUTF` defined for [`java.io.OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html).

You should probably declare `outstream` as `DataOutputStream` reference:

```
DataOutputStream outstream;
```

as the method `writeUTF` *is* defined for [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).

Comment: It's working now, silly of me not to notice that. Thanks so much!